# Give a different link to each result in the database - PHP

Tags: php

I know perfectly well that the question is very strange, in my opinion it is not possible to have an answer or a resolution to it, because I never happened to be able to run into PHP.

The question is this, let's assume that I have a table from which I implement a while loop, within it there are categories, to be precise, 4 categories.

So a table

with 4 results

these 4 results form the categories

now let's assume I have a page, and want to do a while loop to get these 4 results out of the table, and implement them as a button.

BUT!

each of them must point to a different link

```
Value1 = page1.php
Value2 = page2.php
Value3 = page3.php
Value4 = page4.php

page (n) = custom link
```

How could I do this?

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection_file';
$query_string = "QUERY";
$query = mysqli_query($variable_connection_file, $query_string);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
    echo $row['value_name'] ;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you need. Seems like your code should do pretty much you want.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection_file';
$query_string = "QUERY";
$query = mysqli_query($variable_connection_file, $query_string);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
echo '<a href="'.$row['value_link'].'">'.$row['value_name'].'</a>';
 } ?>
```

Comment: no my friend, yes this is the perfect answer if i want implement a link into a while result, my question it s a little bit different, imagine you have 4 result in your table now, you give for all result all different link, you understand now?

Comment: Can you give more info on how your table looks like. How data is stored, name of columns etc...